# Jekyll spams build messages

Tags: ruby, build, jekyll

Whenever I use `jekyll serve` or `jekyll build` Jekyll spams the following message like 50 times:

```
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
Configuration file: F:/path/to/config/_config.yml
... and so on ...
...
```

Build process is fine though. No errors or warnings. Any ideas how to prevent jekyll from doing that?

Comment: If you use `--quiet` with `build`/`serve` does it suppress this message?

Comment: Yes, no messages at all